# How to convert deprecated pymongo commands to new ones automatically

Tags: python, pymongo

I want to convert the deprecated pymongo commands to non deprecated ones. How to do this automatically? I tried to do it manually but in vain

Comment: What do you mean? Which versions ofpymongo? Which commands? anyway I doubt that you can do this in general. Usually when you want to upgrade library versions you actually have to refactor all your code to use the newer API and that's why a lot of libraries keep APIs for a *long* time even when they are deprecated, so that old software will still run for years to come.

Comment: The software is python2.7 I am converting it to python 3 so pymongo commands will also have to be upgraded from pymongo 2 to 3

Comment: Did you try starting from the official [pymongo migration guide](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/migrate-to-pymongo3.html)?